# An application of Open Mapping Theorem and Quotient map

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach Spaces. Let $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear map and T is onto. Let $(y_{n})$ be a sequence in $Y$ converging to $y$ in $Y$.Prove that there exists $x \in X$ and a sequence $(x_{n})$ in $X$ coverging to $x$ such that $T(x)=y$ and $T(x_{n})=y_{n}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My attempt is the following:Let us call $Ker(T)=M$. Then we have an induced map $\hat{T}:X/M \rightarrow Y$ given by $\hat{T} \circ \pi=T$ where $\pi$ is the natural quotient map. With the given condition OPEN MAPPING THEOREM easily implies T is open. Hence $\hat{T}$ is continous and open and hence $\hat{T}$ is bounded below.

Now so, $||\hat{T}(x+M)|| \geq \delta ||x+M||$ $\implies$ $||T(x)|| \geq \delta ||x+M||$.

Now consider $y_{n}$. There exists $x_{n}$ such that $T(x_{n})=y_{n}$. Since $y_{n}$ is convergent we can use the bounded below condition to show that $x_{n} +M$ is cauchy in $X/M$. Hence $x_{n}+M \rightarrow x+M$. Then it is clear after some calculation and manipulation with $\hat{T}$ that $T(x)=y$. But what I'm unable to show is that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ in $X$.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily have $x_n \to x $. But we have
$$
\inf_{m_n \in M} \|x - (x_n + m_n) || = \| x - x_n +M \| \to 0.
$$
This allows you (how exactly?) to modify the sequence $(x_n)_n $ in such a way that the modified sequence satisfies $x_n ' \to x $ and still $T x_n' = y_n$ and $Tx = y $.

Comment: Are u telling $x_n' \rightarrow y$ or tends to $x$

Comment: So the inf tending to zero implies basically that there exists a sequence $k_n$ in M such that $x_n+k_n \rightarrow x$ and then $T(x_n+k_n)$ =$T(x_n)$  tends to $Tx=y$ since $T(x_n)=y_n$

Comment: is this  modification fine?

Comment: @Riju: Yes,  I meant $x $ instead of $y $ (fixed). Also, your modification is fine. My main point was that you do not know that the inf is attained, but you can take $m_n $ with $\|x - (x_n + m_n)\| \leq \| x - x_n +M\| + 1/n \to 0$.